# Flip character horizontally (top lef registration point)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have created Mario character, it is playing different animation like standing, walking, jumping...Everything is ok but flip horizontally.
In my key_down function I set if rightKey is pressed player.scaleX = 1,
else leftKey is pressed player.scaleX = -1;

It works, my english is not so good so here is the link to understand better :

http://www.fastswf.com/vsi-Wps

The only problem is that even if you touch only one time left or right key, 
it will flip player but also it will move the player about 30px (lets say).

I used this before and it works ok if player has center registration point, but now I have top-left registration point and dont know how to fix this?

Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 0):

After scaling by a factor of `-1`, you have to move your DisplayObject to the right by `width` number of pixels. Here's an image illustrating what I mean. The orange dot in the image is the registration point.
[image: Illustration]

And here's what you need to add to the code:

```
player.scaleX = -1;
player.x += width;
```

Comment: But it gives me another problem, after I set scaleX =-1, if I simple add player.x += player.width...then player wont move properly, here is my key_down function,    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
            {
                rightKey = true;
                player.vx = 6;
                player.scaleX = 1;
            }
            else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
            {
                leftKey = true;
                player.vx = -6;
                player.scaleX = -1;
            }

Comment: Then I set onEnterFrame function player.x += player.vx, so the problem is that any time I click left or right arrow key it will run player.x += width or player.x -= width, and it affects players moving.

Comment: Rather than setting `player.scaleX`, set `scaleX` property of its children to mirror them.

Comment: Thans alot for your help, I found the easiest solution, I created boolean var flipped, and now when I flip the player I move him only one time and set var flipped to true if it was false.

Comment: if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
            {
                player.vx = 6;
    
    if (flip == true)
    {
      player.scaleX = 1;
      player.x -= player.width;
      flip = false;
    }
            }